# Configuring Compass on Windows

Tags: css, windows, sass, compass-sass

I'm on Windows, and I have SASS running successfully in my project. Now, I want to include compass so I can take advantage of the pre-written mixins, etc.

First I simply tried this statement from within my working sass file: `@import "compass/css3/transform";`

Naturally, this didn't work since I didn't have compass installed, so I navigated to my Ruby directory and successfully installed the compass gem within `c:/ruby193/bin`. I can now successfully create compass projects within `c:/ruby193/bin`, but that doesn't do me much good.

I need run compass commands within my site, which lives here: `c:/inetpub/mysite`. When I try to do so, however, I get `compass is not recognized as internal or external command`

How can I get compass to work *where* I want it?

**EDIT**: *a large part of my problem was that Ruby was installed without adding itself to the Windows Path environment variables, so I could only run SASS and Compass commands from within the C:/Ruby193/bin directory. This caused problems for me since, as a result, I thought that was where I needed to install compass. Anyhow, after figuring that out, I still haven't been able to get compass to work, but am planning on uninstaling SASS, Compass, and Ruby and giving this thing another try from scratch. I marked Stooboo's answer as correct since it was the best and most accurate, especially given the information he had to work with. Thanks!*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

here's how I do it

(One time)

1. install ruby http://rubyinstaller.org/
2. install compass, in a command window enter

   ```
   gem install compass
   ```
3. to add compass to an MVC project, navigate to project folder and in a command window enter

   ```
   compass create
   ```

   you will get the default config.rb ... but here is my usual one

   ```
   http_path = "/"
   css_dir = "content/css"
   sass_dir = "content/sass"
   images_dir = "images"
   javascripts_dir = "scripts"
   ```
4. to install bootstrap (for more info see https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)
   add

   ```
   require 'bootstrap-sass'
   ```

   to your config.rb

   enter (in your command window)

   ```
   gem install bootstrap-sass
   ```

   (I had to do a (in your command window)
       gem update
   after this but you may not need to)

   enter (in your command window)

   ```
   compass install bootstrap
   ```

(then ... every time you open the solution in Visual Studio)

1. navigate to project folder
2. in a command window enter

   ```
   compass watch
   ```

   (this will monitor project for saves and re-compile the scss files)

Hope that helps

Cheers
Stu

Comment: NOTE: I don't use this method anymore .. instead latest Visual Studio with Web Essentials recompiles as necessary

Comment: Ok, I had an error "while runing gem" > solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26141746/782013

Answer (score 1):

To install Compass, you should open your Windows console with Win+R, `cmd` and run:

```
gem update --system
gem update
gem install compass
```

Don't forget to remove all the stuff that you littered you Ruby installation with.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command in order to add GEM to the Windows Path environment variables:

set PATH=C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;%PATH%

Answer (score 0):

In the Ruby command you should write:

```
gem update --system
```

(this block of code updates all the gems in the Ruby)

Then you install sass like it:

```
gem install sass
```

(You said that you already has sass, so you don't need to write this code again.)

Then, you write this line:

```
gem install compass
```

(Now, you will have compass in your machine)

To know the version that was installed, you can write:

```
compass --version
```

To create a new project in your desktop machine, you can write this line of code:

```
compass create desktop/my-project
```

(This will create a compass folder in the desktop of your machine called my-project. I hope this is helpful.