# Gem install error (sass compass)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I want to install sass and compass, I get this message. Can someone help me?

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\Bk>gem install sass

ERROR:  While executing gem (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
    U+2019 to CP850 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to CP850
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Open up a command prompt and type:

```
chcp 1252
```

Then run the installer again:

`gem install sass`

Unfortunately there's a known issue in some versions of Ruby regarding this.  See [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1025)

Comment: OMG! Finally! Thanks!!

Answer (score 16):

**Here is what worked for me:**

modified **line 70 of registry.rb** (in your ruby installation folder).

Change this line:

```
LOCALE = Encoding.find(Encoding.locale_charmap)
```

to this one:

```
LOCALE = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, but I cannot find the registry.rb file. Nor does `chcp 1252` work for me. Might I ask what the problem exactly is? Thanks in any case.

Comment: where can I find this file?

Comment: in your ruby installation folder

Answer (score -1):

to resolve this problem you have to install an old version of ruby and delete the latest versions on your pc i think there is an error on the latest version,look for this version and download it  [1.8.7](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p374.exe?direct)

Comment: There are many newer versions of Ruby than 1.8.7, http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. Ruby 1.8 and 1.9 have been end-of-lifed as of July, 2014, so I wouldn't recommend using them. https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/

Comment: i tried the lastest version of ruby but i got the same error message when i was trying to install sass