# SASS compiling error using gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp-watch, gulp-ruby-sass

Using `gulp watch`, I get error for sass compiler module as following:

```
[01:41:22] Using gulpfile D:\Workspace\WebDev\agaweed\public_html\wp-content\themes\master\gulpfile.js
[01:41:22] Starting 'watch'...
[01:41:23] Finished 'watch' after 26 ms
[01:41:35] Starting 'styles'...
[01:41:35] 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error: Gem undefined is not installed.
```

I did loaded [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) in `gulpfile.js` and added `watch` task as:

```
// Load plugins
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    del = require('del');

...

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Watch .scss files
  gulp.watch('src/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);

  // Watch .js files
  gulp.watch('src/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

  // Watch image files
  gulp.watch('src/images/**/*', ['images']);

  // Create LiveReload server
  livereload.listen();

  // Watch any files in dist/, reload on change
  gulp.watch(['dist/**']).on('change', livereload.changed);

});
```

Any help with issue is much appreciated :)

Comment: You havent mentioned any code. Please mention the relevant past of your code in the question.

Comment: @RahulDesai sorry for that, I just attached my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gem install error (sass compass)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141589/gem-install-error-sass-compass)

Comment: Check if you have Ruby installed.

Comment: @RahulDesai installed ok.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like 'gulp-sass' installed, also inside your gulpfile you need initialize it.

```
                var sass = require('gulp-sass');
```

Then put in your task

```
                gulp.task('sass', function () {
                  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
               .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
                });
```

Comment: Also, depending on what you are using, you might need to install sass globally npm i sass -g

Comment: I use `gulp-ruby-sass`

Comment: Then at the top of your gulpfile add const sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'); and see if this does the trick for you