# SASS installation issue with ruby

Tags: ruby, sass

I installed:

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
```

When I run this command:

```
gem install sass
```

I face this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
        unknown encoding name - CP720 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

and SASS doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by your current terminal as it is using a codepage (encoding) that is not supported by Ruby, as `Codepage 720` is related with Arabic characters as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815542/rails4-unknown-encoding-name-cp720)

so there are two possible solutions

- change the default system language and restart.
- run command `chcp 1252`if you don't want to change default language
  also check that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141589/gem-install-error-sass-compass/26244869#26244869) as well.

Comment: My problem was resolved
 thank's

Answer (score 0):

Try installing open ssl in your system.

https://geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/openssl/installation/installing_openssl_on_ubuntu_linux.php

And then run `gem install sass`